# How to call objective-c function with double pointer parameter in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pointers

I have [library](https://github.com/VasylKhmil/KVIValidatingTextField) written on objective c language. It has few methods that take double pointer parameters.

I'm trying to use it in project, that is using swift 2.0

```
let failedTextFields = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSArray?>()

        UITextField.checkAllFieldsIfIsValidOnView(self.view,
            withMatchedFields: nil,
            faildedFields: failedTextFields,
            updateStates: updateState)


        let isValid = failedTextFields.memory?.count > 0
```

(`faildedFields` is double pointer parameter)

But when it come to function, it detect, that passed parameter is nil. And because of this, the result is not initialised in function.

Can somebody help me? How can I call this function correctly in swift?

Comment: `&failedTextFields`?

Comment: @Larme than I'm getting an error with suggestion to delete '&' character

Comment: And with `var failedTextFields: NSArray?` as the declaration?

Comment: What about `var` rather than `let`?

Comment: @Larme oh I'm idiot. But swift also didn't help me to understand where is a problem=) Thanks.